# In JavaScript how to grab text element, remove an element, and organize as UL

Tags: javascript

First, and foremost, I'm an amateur with JavaScript so if this is easy my apologies.

I have a flash message that's being rendered on the page that I'm unable to handle correctly so I'm trying to alter it through JavaScript. The page ends up rendering like:

```
<div class="alert-error">
 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
 "
  Row 1: Name can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank; Row 2: Address can't be blank, Email can't be blank
 "
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the text, not the the link, and then either change to an unordered list or just a new line.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
var alpha = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-error')[0].innerText;
alpha.replace(/;/g, '\n');
alpha.split(';').join('\n');
alpha.replace(/;/g, '<br>');
```

It works in the console but **not** when I try to render out the page. I also tried:

```
function newLine(){
 var alpha = document.querySelectorAll('alert-error');
 alpha.forEach(item => {
  item.innerHTML = item.innerText || item.textContent
  item.innerHTML.replace(/;/g, '\n');
 });
};
window.onload = newLine;
```

This does nothing apparently. I'm also getting stuck with the x from the link being around.

Ultimately what I'd like to see is literally:

- Row 1: Name can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank
- Row 2: Address can't be blank, Email can't be blank

Desired HTML:

```
<div class="alert-error">
 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
 <ul>
  <li>Row 1:Name can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank</li>
  <li>Row 2:Address can't be blank, Email can't be blank</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

So how do I grab the text element from the div, strip out the a tag, and then convert the text element from semicolon to new lines/unordered list?

Updated with answer. Made a small change to using a while loop:

```js
  function updateRow() {
    var errorLocation = document.querySelectorAll('.alert-error');
    var text = errorLocation[0].innerText.substr(1);
    text = text.substr(1, text.length - 1);
    var closer = document.createElement('a')
    closer.className = 'close'
    closer.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'alert');
    closer.innerText = 'x';

    var textData = text.split(';')
    var ul = document.createElement('ul')
    var i = 0;
    while (i < textData.length) {
      var li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = textData[i];
      ul.appendChild(li);
      i++;
    }
    errorLocation[0].innerHTML = ''
    errorLocation[0].appendChild(closer);
    errorLocation[0].appendChild(ul);
  };
  updateRow();
```

```css
.alert-error {
background-color: purple;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-error">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
      Row 1: Last name can't be blank, Address can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank, Zip can't be blank, Phone can't be blank, Email Invalid due to bill being an incorrect email, and Hotel must be selected; Row 2: Last name can't be blank, Address can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank, Zip can't be blank, Phone can't be blank, Email Invalid due to frank@no being an incorrect email, Check in cannot be before check out, and Hotel must be selected; Row 3: Last name can't be blank, Address can't be blank, City can't be blank, State can't be blank, Zip can't be blank, and Phone can't be blank
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to perform my best with the limited information available. I have created a fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/djqp8b6f/

Let me know if it suits your needs. The code parses the text of the `div`. We split by `;` and then do a `for loop` appending `li` items in each iteration.

```
function applyFix(){
 var alpha = document.querySelectorAll('.alert-error');
 var text = alpha[0].innerText.substr(4); // removing extra " at start
 text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1); // remove extra " at end
 var aLink = document.createElement('a') // recreating the a-link
 aLink.className='close'
 aLink.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'alert');
 aLink.innerText = 'x';

 var textData = text.split(';') // performs the conversion of text to li(s)
 var ul = document.createElement('ul')
 for(var i=0;i<textData.length;i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerText = textData[i];
  ul.appendChild(li);
 }
 alpha[0].innerHTML = ''
 alpha[0].appendChild(aLink);
 alpha[0].appendChild(ul);
};
```

Comment: Ran this against the live code and it's super close. The substr was including the quotation marks. Which was my bad as I was pulling in visually from the HTML but it's actually just implied. Changing the substr values to 1 makes this 100% work.